# How can I convert an ISO language code to its language name in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iso

I'm getting ISO language codes from an API in my iOS app. For example, `en` for English, `hi` for Hindi, etc. I'd like to convert these ISO codes to their respective language names.

This is returned by the API:

```
"category": "TVCHANEL",
"chanellanguage": "ar",
```

How can I do this? Do I have to create a dictionary with an ISO code as key for every language?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `NSLocale` for this. Please refer below examples

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar"];
NSLog(@"%@", [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:@"ar"]);
Output: العربية

NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"];
NSLog(@"%@", [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:@"ar"]);
Output: Arabic
```

I hope this is what you require.

Comment: I have a scenario where language code is "fre" but it gives me nil whereas for "fra" it returns the correct value "French". ISO 639-2 code for French are both fre or fra. Could you please help.